# Pourquoi le pronom « le » est-il utilisé dans « mais sa mère l'est » ?

Tags: pronoms, attributs

Dans ce dialogue le pronom *le* remplace « d'accord avec moi » :

> Est-ce qu'elle est d'accord avec toi ?
>   — Non, elle n'est pas d'accord mais sa mère l'est.

Je pensais que *le* devait être utilisé seulement pour remplacer des choses définies masculines, par exemple :

> Est-ce que tu connais John ?
>   — Oui, je *le* connais.

Dans ce cas, « John » est défini donc j'utilise *le*.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut m'expliquer pourquoi l'utilisation du pronom *le* est correcte dans le premier dialogue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dans « être d'accord » *d'accord* n'est pas un nom, mais une locution adverbiale, plus proche de l'adjectif que du nom, et est un attribut. L'emploi du pronom personnel *le* découle de la construction *être* suivi d'un attribut.

Pour bien comprendre on peut faire le rapprochement avec des phrases comme :

> Elle n'est pas grande mais sa mère l'est.

De même si la locution attribut contient *de* ou une autre préposition, c'est *le* qui sera utilisé :

> - je suis *en* retard
> - oh ! je **le** suis aussi.

Donc, le pronom personnel *le*, dit dans ce cas « pronom neutre », ne sert pas qu'à remplacer des noms. Outre son emploi pour remplacer un attribut, il peut aussi remplacer un groupe verbal ou une proposition objet.

> Monsieur Jourdain dit de la prose depuis longtemps, sans **le** savoir.

Dans la phrase ci-dessus le pronom *le* reprend « dit de la prose ».

> Cet homme est plus rusé qu'il ne le dit.

Dans la phrase ci-dessus le pronom *le* reprend « Cet homme est plus rusé ».

---

Je voudrais maintenant revenir à l'expression « être d'accord », et la question en note, pourquoi « le » et pas « en ». Question tout à fait pertinente et à laquelle je vais essayer d'apporter des éléments de réponse.

« En être d'accord » existe bel et bien, même si de nos jours « être d'accord » est plus courant. [Grevisse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grevisse) dit qu'on peut être d'accord « de quelque chose » ou « sur quelque chose » (  ce dernier est plus fréquent de nos jours). Du moment qu'on peut dire qu'on est « d'accord de quelque chose », l'emploi du « en »  pour reprendre un élément est logique grammaticalement.

> Toute votre justice en est-elle d'accord ? [Corneille, Cid. V, 8]
>
> J’en suis d’accord, il nous faut aller plus loin encore ... (dans un [texte oral de janvier 2014](http://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/14/pdf/cr-soc/13-14/c1314034.pdf))

De nos jours cependant l'emploi de « en être d'accord » n'est pas général et semble inconnu dans certaines régions de France.

Et donc, pour reprendre ton exemple, compte tenu du fait qu'on peut dire « en être d'accord », je ne serais pas choquée d'entendre :

> Est-ce qu'elle en est d'accord avec toi ?
>   — Non, elle n'en est pas d'accord mais sa mère en est.

Mais dans ce cas c'est « en être d'accord » qui est utilisé à chaque fois.

<sub>* source *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey, éditions Le Robert</sub>

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Ça fait sens pour moi ! Donc "le" dans mon example est un "pronom neutre" et pourtant il fait sens maintenant :) En plus, ton explanation sur l'utilisation de "en" avec l'expression "être d'accord" a clarifié mon doutê. Ainsi, merci de nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

Le pronom "le" prend la place d'un nom.

Dans votre cas, le pronom "le" est utilisé en tant qu'attribut et remplace le nom "accord", ce qui signifie donc :

> - Est-ce qu'elle est d'accord avec toi?
> - Non, elle n'est pas d'accord mais sa mère est d'accord avec moi.

Il permet donc d'éviter la répétition.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Ça ne fait pas sense pour moi - je suis desolé. "Accord" est un nom - c'est ok - mais il y a un "de" avant de "accord" - donc "de accord". Si il y a un "de", pourquoi est-ce que je ne peux pas dire "elle n'est pas d'accord mais sa mère en est"?

Comment: @cldjr C'est une expression « être d'accord ».

Comment: Oui, l'exemple avec "être d'accord" n'est pas le plus évident à comprendre. Un meilleur exemple avec un adjectif plus simple serait : "Est-ce qu'elle est grande ?" "Non mais sa mère l'est", équivalent de "Non mais sa mère est grande",

Answer (score 0):

dans

> Est-ce qu'elle est d'accord avec toi ?
>   — Non, elle n'est pas d'accord mais sa mère **l**'est.

"Le" est un pronom  qui remplace  "est d'accord à" et qui joue le rôle d'attribut par rapport à "elle".

La cible de "le" -qu'on appelle "antécédent"- est une expression qui a été citée juste avant l'expression courante(celle qui contient "le") donc elle est supposée être **connue dans le contexte global** d’où l'usage d'un pronom défini...

on ne peut pas utiliser "en" tout d'abord par ce que la fonction grammaticale de "être d'accord" ne le permet pas(c'est pas un  C.O.I) et même si on va supposer qu'il est possible d'utiliser "en" dans cette expression,le résultat serait quelque chose du genre "j'en suis" ou "il en est" ce qui donne  mal à l'oreille et n'a pas de sens :ça ne se dit pas...