# Is "d'accord" a contraction?

Tags: usage, contractions

I'm currently learning French (it's not going very well, but hey, I'm trying. :))

I was looking at the word *d'accord*. I noticed the apostrophe. Is this a contraction?

I was thinking, possibly, "de accord" or "du accord".

Am I right, or wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit bien de la contraction de *de* et *accord*.

On dit « ils sont d'accord » de la même façon qu'on dirait « ils sont de connivence » ou « ils sont de sortie » ou « cela est de mise » ou « il est de convenance ».

---

It is indeed a contraction of *de* and *accord*.

A few other phrasings have the same structure as “ils sont d'accord”. For example, “ils sont de connivence” or “ils sont de sortie” or “cela est de mise” or “il est de convenance”.

Also, according to French's elision rules, *du accord* isn't a valid combination. In different circumstances, *de le accord* contracts to *de l'accord*.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information! I didn't know anything about the elision rules. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

When the expression *être d'accord* originated (early Middle-Ages) it was meant as the contraction of *de*. The primary meaning of *accord* being *pacte* (an agreement). But nowadays *être d'accord* is perceived as a lexical unit and absolutely no one will think of the *d'* as a contraction.

For more on the phrase *être d'accord* you can have a look at [this post](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/10972/358)

Comment: *Paraitre*, *sembler*, *devenir*, *finir*, *tomber*, *mettre*… *d'accord* are in use as well. It may be “perceived” like a lexical unit by some, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

*D'accord* est une expression idiomatique synonyme de *s'entendre, se concerter*.

> Ils se sont mis *d'accord* : ils ont la même opinion, ils ont les mêmes intentions.

Pour répondre à votre interrogation, on peut comprendre : *on est **d**'accord* comme *on **s**'accorde bien* ; mais c'est la contraction de l'expression ;

> D'[un commun] accord.

Comment: Aucun rapport avec le sujet, mais il me semble qu'il faudrait ici dire *expression idiomatique* et pas *idiome*. http://cnrtl.fr/definition/idiome

Comment: @fkraiem Votre remarque est prise en compte.