# Quelle est l'utilité du pronom « le » dans « aussi unique que vous l'êtes » ?

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe

Aujourd'hui, j'ai vu une pub pour une banque au centre-ville de Montréal avec le texte ci-dessous:

> Des services bancaires aussi uniques que vous l'êtes.

La traduction en anglais est:

> Banking services as unique as you are.

Dans la phrase « aussi uniques que vous l'êtes », on trouve que le pronom « l' » est utilisé, mais il manque un pronom similaire dans la traduction anglaise. Pour un anglophone comme moi, ce pronom semble être inutile. Alors, voici ma question: pourquoi est-ce qu'on dit la phrase ci-dessus mais pas celle ci-dessous:

> Des services bancaires aussi uniques que vous êtes.

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/pourquoi-le-pronom-le-est-il-utilis%c3%a9-dans-mais-sa-m%c3%a8re-lest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pour comprendre cette phrase, il faudrait écrire en anglais :

> Banking services as unique as you are *unique*,

le `l'` répond à la question de *qui* vous êtes : vous n'êtes pas comme tout le monde puisque vous êtes *unique*, c'est pour ne pas répéter ce mot :

> Des services bancaires aussi uniques que vous êtes unique.

que l'on dit, à cause de l'expression *aussi ... que*.

> Des services bancaires aussi uniques que vous *l'* êtes.

Si l'on ne voulait pas insister sur cette unicité on pourrait écrire simplement,

> Des services bancaires aussi uniques que vous.

...mais certains pourraient comprendre qu'on les compare à des services bancaires, ce qui, du point de vue hexagonal n'est pas un compliment.

Answer (score 0):

Je doûte que ce slogan soit bien retranscrit car il y a une faute d'accord, ce devrait être :

> Des services bancaires aussi uniques que vous l'êtes.

J'ai trouvé en revanche [celui-ci](https://www.bmo.com/principal/particuliers/comptes-bancaires/services-bancaires/unique-fr) :

> Une expérience bancaire aussi unique que vous l’êtes.

qui veut bien dire, comme l'a aussi répondu entretemps cl-r :

> Une expérience bancaire aussi unique que vous êtes unique.

Comment: Oui,  vous êtes juste.  J'ai fait un erreur d'accord. Il devrait être  « des services bancaires aussi uniques...». Je  vais l'éditer.

Comment: Beaucoup d'anglicismes : Oui, vous avez raison. J'ai fait une erreur d'accord. Ce devrait être « des services bancaires aussi uniques… ». Je vais le corriger.