# In the sentence "Charles est beau, mais son frère ne l'est pas" what does the "l'" stand for?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

In the sentence "Charles est beau, mais son frère ne l'est pas" what does the "l'" stand for? Does it stand for the adjective "Beau"?

Comment: Similar: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/pourquoi-le-pronom-le-est-il-utilis%c3%a9-dans-mais-sa-m%c3%a8re-lest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It is the elided of "le" which is in this case a pronoun refering to the qualificative "beau". It could refer to qualificatives that are not adjectives, as in:

> "Es-tu l'assassin de mon père ?"
>
> "Non, je ne **le** suis pas".